# Cambie de directorio mi proyecto en react y ahora no funciona

Tags: reactjs

Cambie de directorio mi proyecto y ahora no anda, ya hice un replace con sublime text y cambie todas las rutas viejas del proyecoto a las nuevas

Ruta antigua: `/Users/Santiago/Desktop/Work`
Ruta nueva: `/Users/Santiago/Desktop/Work/frontend`

Error: `Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/santiago/Desktop/Work" while parsing file: /Users/santiago/Desktop/Work/frontend/src/index.js`

Contenido de ese index.js

```js
'use strict';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import framework from './framework';
import domready from 'domready';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') require('./util/stats')();

domready(framework);
```

Lei por ahi que es algo de babel, pero en todos lados dicen que lo instale y yo la lo tengo instalado, simplemente movi de lugar el proyecto

Comment: ¿Moviste todo a la nueva ruta, incluyendo node_modules, .babelrc, .etc?

Comment: Yes bro, al principio me di cuenta que finder me habia dejado los dotfiles ahi logicamente pero recien los movi con la terminal y aun sigue fallando

Answer (score 0):

Trata instalar nuevamente

`npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save
npm install babel-preset-react --save`

Comment: ¿Por qué no desde una sola línea? `npm i -S babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react`.

Comment: Puedes elaborar un poco más porque piensas que repetir una instalación debería solucionar el problema? Tratemos que ser un poco más preciso en SO que la mesa ayuda de M$ recomendando de reiniciar el equipo por si acaso.